# Opera css: box-shadow bug

Tags: css, opera

I have been busy creating my website, however in the process of testing my in-progress main page on Opera I noticed that It was adding a horizontal scroll bar. After cutting bits out of my page I noticed that if I only left a single div with the ID feature the problem would still occur. I tried searching it by couldn't find anything on it... anywhere.
Here is a link to a page exampling the problem [Opera Box Shadow Bug](http://www.webflourish.com.au/operashadow.html)
It is important to note that it only occurs in Opera and as part of the CSS3 Spec it is stated that box-shadow does not at height or width.
Does anybody have a easy solution for this? The only thing that I found that worked was to put a containing Div around the box shadow div, or around several divs and set overflow:hidden; , which is far from ideal. 
I haven't checked Opera for Windows but it is occurring on Opera for Mac (v11.50).

Comment: Try giving **width: 100%** for the id. If it didn't work, give **overflow:hidden** for the same id.

Comment: @Mah overflow: hidden; for the same ID doesn't do anything as the box shadow is not part of the div. The div was already meant to have width: 100%; my bad. Uploading the up to date files now.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your file in Windows Opera and it is displaying the same way.
The only way I was able to make it work was to also wrap a div around your #feature div, add overflow:hidden, and a larger height. Here is my code

```
html, body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
#hidden{
height:400px;
overflow:hidden;
}
#feature {
width:100%;
height: 375px;
background: #000;
box-shadow: 0 4px 4px 4px #000;
}


<div id="hidden">
   <div id="feature">
   </div>
</div>
```

Besides this, I would use a 1px wide image with repeat.

Comment: Hmmm, pretty much what I said in my question, how would you do the 1px  image? you saying you would use a picture background for the shadow instead of css? Interesting that Opera would have a bug as simple as this, its not IE we are talking about here!

Comment: Yes, I'm aware you stated that in your question and it seems you also answered it. If you are concerned with how Opera displays the box shadow and the #feature div being nested is far from ideal, you could use a .png background-image repeated horizontally. However, I'm not sure of the purpose for your #feature div so this may be far from ideal too.

Comment: On the site that I was having the problem with I having a containing Div that contains my header and feature DIVs it is set to overflow: hidden; I was merely wondering if there was another way people were solving this and for that matter who else was having this issue! I prefer to use layouts that don't require images so I think I will avoid the background-image. This is the site I was having the issue with and had previously solved it http://www.webflourish.com.au

Comment: I would also avoid using an image considering it can be done with CSS. I worked on the problem last night for a while and those are the only two fixes I could find. Just one of those strange occurrences that we must deal with.

Comment: Thats what I thought, as stated in the question was just wondering how others were dealing with it.

Answer (score 0):

The bug seems to be solved at least in Opera 11.60.

Comment: I have 11.62 and this bug is present